# Когда стоит использовать ES2015 в JS?

Tags: javascript

Стоит пользоваться ES2015 для сайта и если да, то в каких случаев?
Может есть примеры сайтов которые работают на ES2015, пришлите их пожалуйста.

Comment: Эм, всегда? . .

Comment: Пользуйтесь лучше ES2020 и полезным сайтом caniuse.com

Answer (score 0):

ES (EcmaScript) - это лишь спецификация, по которой браузеры внедряют новый функционал. Надо его использовать или нет - дело твое. Вопрос лишь в том, какой % людей использует подходящую версию браузера.

А на сайте [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) можно указать тот функционал, который тебя интересует, и узнать % людей, которые смогут пользоваться этой возможностью. Сайт так же работает с HTML и CSS.